# Software for solving SDPs

Tags: matlab, mathematical-optimization

I have been using cvx for doing some experiments with my SDPs. Although it is very easy to use, it is quite slow. I cannot run reasonably large instances in reasonable time. Hence would like someone to point to some faster software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find a list of Semidefinite Programming codes on Hans Mittelmann's [Decision Tree for Optimization Software](http://plato.asu.edu/sub/nlores.html#semidef). At least some of the codes are implemented in Matlab (like *cvx*, right?) or have a Matlab interface.